# Обработчик форм javascript

Tags: javascript, html, form

На странице есть две формы, одинаковых, пока с одинаковыми `id`:

```
<form action="/order/" method="post" id="orderform">
  <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="ФИО">
  <input class="masked-phone" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Номер      телефона">
  <input type="hidden" name="goods_id" value="10" />
  <input type="submit"  value="Заказать">
</form>
```

и обработчик:

```
jQuery.extend({
    getQueryParameters : function(str) {
        return (str ||     document.location.search).replace(/(^\?)/,'').split("&").map(function(n){return n = n.split("="),this[n[0]] = n[1],this}.bind({}))[0];
}
});

function jsonifyForm(src) {
    var result = Object.create(null);
    var splitted_pairs = src.serialize().split('&');
    var kv;

    for (var i in splitted_pairs) {
        kv = splitted_pairs[i].split('=');
        result[kv[0]] = decodeURIComponent(kv[1]);
    }

    _.extend(result, $.getQueryParameters());

    return JSON.stringify(result);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#orderform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: e.currentTarget.action,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsonifyForm($(this))
        }).then(function() {
            $('#orderform')[0].reset();
            window.location.href = 'success.php';
        });
    });

    $('.masked-phone').inputmask('+7 (999) 999-99-99');
});
```

Пробовал заменить `id`  на классы, срабатывают обе формы независимо от того какая задействовалась. 
Как переделать код обработчика чтобы он обрабатывал одну из форм, в зависимости от того какая использовалась?

Comment: что значит - "срабатывают обе формы" и "задействовалась"?  Не используйте повторяющиеся id в html элементах и отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код.

Comment: В смысле на сервер постбек приходит ответ с обеих форм, вторая соответственно выдает ошибку.С id понимаю что два одинаковых использовать нельзя, я не понимаю как их обработать одним обработчиком. Код отформатировал, спасибо. Не сразу понял как.

Comment: Как инициируется/вызывается submit форм? В них есть кнопки для этого, или Вы это делаете в коде? А, вижу кнопку.

Comment: Хм, непонятно, как нажатие кнопки `type="submit"` внутри одной формы может вызвать submit другой формы :( , или я чего-то не вижу?

Comment: С одинаковым id как было раньше то еще понятно. Но вот сделал на каждой форме уникальный id, отдельный обработчик на каждую форму по id-шнику, как рекомендовали ниже,и все ровно на сервер приходит дублированный ответ. А это уже я никак не могу понять как так(

Comment: попробуйте максимально упростить код, посылайте просто `$(this).serialize();`, закомментируйте код внутри `done`, убедитесь, что в консоли нет ошибок. Вы уверены, что разные формы постят на сервер, а не одна и та же два раза?

Comment: Вы оказались правы, срабатывал код с другого подключенного скрипта, о котором я и не знал (думал там только скрипт поп-апа а оказалось еще один обработчик). Из за этого было это двойное срабатывание. Последовал тогда Вашему совету, все упростил, переписал заново, и все отлично работает, спасибо за участие в дискуссии и за дельный совет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну так в чем проблема то

```
<form action="/order/" method="post" id="orderform1">
    ...
</form>
```

и

```
<form action="/order/" method="post" id="orderform2">
    ...
</form>
```

обработка

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#orderform1').submit(function(e) {
        ....
    });
    $('#orderform2').submit(function(e) {
        ....
    });
});
```

Comment: Последовал Вашему примеру, и все работает, спасибо за помощь! Тогда в конце рабочего дня моего соображения уже не хватало. А все оказалось просто и логично.